# Is there bad continuity with the Kes & Paris storyline in "Before and After"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In [VOY: Before and After](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Before_and_After_(episode)), Kes and Tom Paris are married. Paris talks of the Year of Hell, when they lost Janeway and B'Ellana who was very special to him (the budding romance shown throughout the series). Later Kes backward time jumps to the Year of Hell where she is giving birth to Linnis, their daughter.

Now, I know the Ocompa have short life spans, but Paris has just recently (within a year) lost this very special person, dated Kes, married Kes, got her pregnant and gone through the pregnancy, all while they're literally living the 'Year of Hell'. It doesn't seem to stack up...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you've got the timing mixed up. In this timeline Janeway and Torres were killed relatively early in the Year of Hell, with Kes and Tom starting a relationship shortly afterwards.

Note that when an Ocampan becomes [receptive](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Elogium), their partner has only one chance to impregnate them. On top of that, Ocampans age very rapidly indeed, so there's every possibility that what humans (average mortality 100+ years) would regard as a pretty new relationship of only a few months could move along *very quickly* when an Ocampan (average mortality 9 years) was involved, from the early stages to pregnancy and into parenthood all within the same year.

Comment: You might also want to note that 3-4 years later Harry is in a relationship with Tom's daughter and having a child of his own.